# In Keystone, how to have a field that can have an arbitrary number of items?

Tags: keystonejs

I would like to have a model that has an array of a particular things, and be able to in the CMS add or remove items from that array.

Each of the items in the array would have a variety of properties such as an image url, title, subtitle, description

How can this be achieved?

Thanks

edit: apparently cant be done because the API's been churning for 2+ years
https://github.com/keystonejs/keystone/issues/153

Comment: You mean something like [relationships](http://keystonejs.com/docs/database/#relationships)?

Comment: thanks for the link, but that's not quite what I need. I found an open issue from February 2014 relating to this: https://github.com/keystonejs/keystone/issues/153

It's not a one-to-many relationship, but a one-has-many relationship, and I need to be able to modify the nested data in the same page